# Kivy and Google Play 64-bit

Tags: android, python, google-play, kivy

As you may know, from August 1, 2019 all Android-releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
Will Kivy + Buildozer allow us to create such apps?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, what have you tried ?

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1519)

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, [here's](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1519) an open issue on the Kivy repository about plans for Kivy to support Google's upcoming 64-bit binary requirement. Here's a comment from one of the devs:

> In https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html:
>
> > In August 2019, Play will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions.
>
> I think we should default to arm64-v8a to prevent issues later, and start thinking how we can do multiple targets compilation and embedded them in one APK.

...which has three thumbs-ups.

Answer (score 4):

Buildozer already allows you to create such apps, just change the `android.arch` configuration token in buildozer.spec to `arm64-v8a` instead of the default `armeabi-v7a`.

We don't support APKs with multiple architectures bundled together, mostly because this would significantly increase their size due to all the compiled components, but you can upload one APK of each type to Google Play.

We'll probably update the defaults and provide more documentation about it within the next few months.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Just go to line 232 in the `buildozer.spec` file and change the `arch` to  `arm64-v8a` and then build the app and then again build the app by changing the `arch` of `buildozer.spec` file to `armeabi-v7a`. On Google Play console, upload both the files.