# Kivy buildozer 64 bit apk not being accepted by google play store

Tags: kivy, 64-bit, buildozer

Google Play Store was not accepting my 32 bit apk. So I followed the instruction from this link https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1519 to change the android.arch to arm64-v8a in the buildozer spec file.
I did exactly that. Here are all the steps that I took:

```
1. Change android.arch from armeabi-v7a to arm64-v8a. Save the spec file.
2. Run sudo buildozer android release . Get an unsigned apk file.
3. Run zipalign -v -p 4 kindact-0.1-release-unsigned.apk kindact-0.1-release-unsigned-aligned.apk to get an aligned apk.
4. Copy that file along with the key file into a folder contained apksigner. 
5. Run sudo ./apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out kindact-release.apk kindact-0.1-release-unsigned-aligned.apk to get a signed apk.
6. Upload that file to the App Releases in Google Play Store.
```

I get the same error **"This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 7212."** as in the 32 bit version, before editing the buildozer spec file.

On the same Google Play Store page, I click on the dropdown of the apk and the **Native platforms** is still showing **armeabi-v7a**.
[image]
I try uploading 1 32 bit apk and 1 64 bit apk as suggested here [Kivy and Google Play 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312843/kivy-and-google-play-64-bit) but still get the same error.
[image]

What did I do wrong? Please help.

Comment: I think buildozer/p4a has just cached the previous (armeabi-v7a) build. Try deleting the .buildozer directory in your app dir and running the build again, this should refresh everything. This behaviour is a bug, it will be fixed in the next buildozer and p4a releases.